# Uncaught Reference Error: Jsonbody is not defined at Request.request

Tags: json, request

I am trying to show details of an api call in my electron app. [this is the api](http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=mycallback) and sample json data:

```
[
{
  ID: 596,
  title: "Carolyn Wood",
  content: "<p>Turning away bad clients can leave you feeling oddly guilty. They&#8217;re sort of like alcoholic or meth head cousins who force you, by their own bad behavior into denying them things you wouldn&#8217;t deny other people. You&#8217;re left feeling not quite yourself. </p> ",
  link: "https://quotesondesign.com/carolyn-wood/",
  custom_meta: {
    Source: "<a href="http://twitter.com/carywood/status/2121020860">Twitter</a>"
   } 
 }
]
```

I am using `request` module to fetch data and `JSON.parse(body)` to get the object like below:

```
let request = require('request');
request("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=mycallback",
(err, response, body)=>{
let jsonBody = JSON.parse(body);
let randQuote = jsonBody[0]["content"];
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = randQuote;
});
```

In console, I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonBody is not defined
at Request.request [as _callback] (D:\ElectronDev\ElectronBasics\quote-widget\index.js:8
```

pointing on this line `JSON.parse(body)`. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response from the endpoint has some extra characters at the start of the response and that's the reason the `JSON.parse` can not parse it into object and `jsonBody` is undefined.

Here is the fix to your specific response for [this](http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&_jsonp=mycallback). Change your line of code to this.

```
let jsonBody = JSON.parse(body.substring("/**/mycallback(".length, body.length - 1));
```

Hope this helps.